Need help solving $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt x}{\cos(2x)+6x}$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt x\ln(2x+1)}{\cos(2x)+6x}$
For the first I tried making it $\frac{\frac{1}{\cos(2x)+6x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt x}}$ so it can be $\frac{0}{0}$ and do de l'hospital but it goes again at $\frac{0}{0}$ so I suppose I just dont know something hence the reason im asking this question.
and following that comes solving the second one.
I need to find their sum so I can find if it converges or diverges.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Next time please don't delete and repost, instead edit and wait until the question is reopened

@SineoftheTime Ok sorry my bad. Just thought this would be faster

Rewrite the first limit as $\frac1{\frac{\cos 2x}{\sqrt x}+\frac{6x}{\sqrt x}}$

Hint for both: as $x\to\infty$, $\cos(2x)+6x\sim6x$    (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition) Note also that if your 2nd limit is $0$ then obviously so is the 1st.

"I need to find their sum": better not split it in two limits. Directly, as $x\to\infty$, $$\frac{(\sqrt x)(1+\ln(2x+1))}{\cos(2x)+6x}\sim\frac{(\sqrt x)\ln x}{6x}\to0.$$

1st limit:
you can divide both the numerator and denominator with $x$ - the greatest power in the whole fraction, you get $$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt {\frac{x}{x^2}}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{x}+\frac{6x}{x}} = \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}{\frac{\cos(2x)}{x} + 6}$$
Now the numerator $\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$, and note that $\frac{\cos(2x)}{x} \to 0$ as well since $\cos(2x) \in [-1, 1]\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$, so you get $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt x}{\cos(2x)+6x} = \frac{0}{0 + 6} = 0$$
2nd limit:
You can again multiply both the numerator and denominator with $1/x$, you get $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\ln(2x+1)}{\sqrt x}}{\frac{\cos(2x)+6x}{x}}$$
Now you can do L'Hopital for the fraction in the numerator, you get $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\overbrace{\frac{2}{2x + 1}}^\text{derivative of ln(2x+1)}}{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}_{\text{derivative of } \sqrt x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4 \sqrt x}{2x+1}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{4 \frac{1}{\sqrt x}}{2 + \frac{1}{x}}= \color{red}0$$
So you have esentially a $0$ in the numerator of your original limit. The denominator is the same as in the first limit, so as explained above, you'll have $0+6$. Finally you get $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt x\ln(2x+1)}{\cos(2x)+6x}=\frac{\color{red} 0}{0+6}=0$$

we have :
$$\forall x> 1/6$$
$$0\le|\frac{\sqrt x}{\cos(2x)+6x}|\le \frac{\sqrt x}{6x-1}$$
and
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt x}{6x-1} =0 $$therfore  $$\lim_{x\to \infty}|\frac{\sqrt x}{\cos(2x)+6x}|=0$$
Then:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{\sqrt x}{\cos(2x)+6x}=0$$
In the same way, try to prove the other.
